# Implicit Google API authorization for site using Google Cloud Search

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-api-js-client

I'm trying to authorize a user to use Google Cloud Search on our company intranet (using company domain). If the user has already authenticated with GSuite, it's as simple as calling `gapi.auth2.authorize()`.

However, if the user has not authenticated with Google (i.e., no google cookie exists in the browser), the user is prompted to confirm the email address needed to authorize (we have the user's company email available to pass as the `login_hint` field to `authorize()`).

We want to provide a...

(1) seamless user experience across browsers. The popup solution is not seamless between browsers as some browsers automatically block popups that aren't triggered through a click.

(2) GCS capabilities that are handled without additional prompts. It's not a "search app", it's merely the search bar of an intranet site.  It's also a bad user experience to have a popup window authorize for the sole purpose of searching.

Is there a way to use the api key/application ID to implicitly authorize the user behind-the-scenes so that the user can perform search without experiencing the aforementioned issues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely,

Try Service Account Authorization,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google API Client library to make API calls from backend. Here's the reference for Cloud Search [this](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudsearch_v1.html).

Instead of using access token generated by OAuth authorisation in browser, you can [grant following scope](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) and make search queries from your back end and send the results to the front end:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud_search

Check out the Cloud Search API from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/reference/rest/).